# Get element with min attribute

Tags: xml, xquery

With Xquery I want to get the row which has the min sortOrder. In the example below the row with id=3.

```
<table>
  <row id="1"><attribute identifier="sortOrder">120</attribute><attribute identifier="mainContent">Test 3</attribute></row>
  <row id="2"><attribute identifier="sortOrder">130</attribute><attribute identifier="mainContent">Test 1</attribute></row>
  <row id="3"><attribute identifier="sortOrder">10</attribute><attribute identifier="mainContent">Test 2</attribute></row>
</table>
```

Anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find min value with the min() function and then look it up in the rows:

```
let $min := min(//row/attribute[@identifier='sortOrder'])
return //row[attribute[@identifier='sortOrder'] = $min]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the code above, as you can see there can be more than one attribute with the same content in an other row. How can I add the attribute identifier to the return part?

Comment: Maybe you also have a hint for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643317/for-loop-with-min-value ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to an XQuery 3.0 implementation, then I am quite taken by this functional approach:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $apply := function($xs, $f, $xpath) {
  $xpath($xs[. = $f($xs)])
} return


$apply(
    //row/attribute[@identifier eq 'sortOrder'],
    fn:min#1,
    function($x) {
        $x/parent::node()
    }
)
```

One of the nice properties of this approach is you only need to do the search on the initial data once i.e. `//row/attribute[@identifier eq 'sortOrder']` only needs to be evaluated once, which may be more efficient.

Another nice property is that the lambda `$apply` is a generic function, and so you could re-use it for any function that would operate on `$xs` for example `fn:max#1` :-)