# For loop with min value

Tags: xml, xquery

I got the following XML code and want to sort it by the attribute identifier `sort_order`.

```
<products>
 <product>
  <row>
   <attribute identifier="SORT_ORDER">60100</attribute>
  </row>
  <row>
   <attribute identifier="SORT_ORDER">60104</attribute>
  </row>
 </product>
 <product>
  <row>
   <attribute identifier="SORT_ORDER">400</attribute>
  </row>
  <row>
   <attribute identifier="SORT_ORDER">398</attribute>
  </row>
 </product>
</products>
```

What I tried so far with the help of  [Get element with min attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641740/get-element-with-min-attribute/25641932?noredirect=1#comment40066848_25641932):

```
for $a in //products/product 
order by number ( $a/row[attribute[@identifier='sortOrder']=string(min(//attribute[@identifier='SORT_ORDER']) ) ]/attribute[@identifier='SORT_ORDER'])
return $a
```

But the output with the code above is like the input. There is no error.
Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for $a in //products/product 
   order by min ($a//attribute[@identifier='SORT_ORDER'])
return $a
```